# Django won't display image from database in HTML

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

Hi I am trying to get user profile images to display from a Django MySQL database corresponding to the user that is logged in..

Here is my settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]

# Media files

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
#MEDIA_DIRS = [MEDIA_DIR, ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin/media/'
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^smartcity/',include('smartcity.urls')),
    #url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    #url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='registration'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

And this is what I have in the html file:

```
src="{% static 'user.userprofile.picture.url' %}"
```

This is my table i am trying to retrieve the picture from:
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE2M2.png)

I'm not sure how to get it to display, I thought my URL mapping was correct as i can view the image if i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_images/trump.jpg

Any ideas? Sorry I am a bit of noobie.

Answer (score 0):

`FileField` uploads to the media side of things, not static, so you just have to do;

```
<img src="{{ user.userprofile.picture.url }}" alt="" />
```

Here is an example of this scenario; https://www.simplifiedpython.net/django-file-upload-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you it worked! i was trying to do it with these % but wasn't working.. yours worked with the double brackets